# Согласование во множественном числе

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли здесь глаголы поставлены во множественном числе или слова "каждый" "отдельный" играют роль?

Это особенное – достоинство, с которым коллектив и каждый отдельный сотрудник преодолевают трудности, и шаг за шагом, приближаются к тем высоким целям, которые лежат в основе нашей философии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно. Но после "шаг за шагом" запятая не ставится.

Ой... И перед – тоже не ставится. Однородные члены же.

Comment: Спасибо)))

Comment: Но почему-то Ворд подчеркивает отсутствие запятой после "трудностей" как ошибку и успокаивается только при таком варианте:
Это особенное – достоинство, с которым коллектив и каждый отдельный сотрудник преодолевают трудности, и шаг за шагом приближаются к тем высоким целям, которые лежат в основе нашей философии.

P.S. Что однородные - это я вижу, но может есть еще какое-то правило, о котром я не знаю?

Comment: Нет, Ворд тут врёт. Он неверно определяет границу распространенного определения.

У вас тут ещё два "которых", я сначала не заметил. Тоже не есть хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Ворд почему-то также не воспринимает пассивные конструкции. После "трудности" запятая действительна не нужна. Т.к. здесь один и тот же субъект: преодолевает трудности кто - коллектив, и приближается к целям - кто - тоже коллектив.